# How to send event from laravel to Javascript client about save() to database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I need refresh js DOM when database is updated without reload page.

In first time i thought send ajax post with delay 3 second. But it's bad idea.

Right way, server must announce js.

How to send  event from laravel to Javascript client about save method to database mySql?

Comment: Google for websockets or javascript sockets. Maybe that will be an option for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the easy way is use Pusher (https://pusher.com/), you create an free account and you will get the API keys. You use this in your .env file, you can use `config/broadcasting.php` but in .env is the best pratice.

In Laravel you may fire an Event (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events) that implements ShouldBroadcast (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#marking-events-for-broadcast)

In your `config/broadcasting.php` you must see if Pusher is your default Broadcasting Driver ou set it in .env, so Laravel will make everything under the hood for you.

In your Pusher dashboard they give you how to use this in your front.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has built in events that can use Pusher to broadcast the information to your front-end.  Check it out: https://laravel.com/docs/master/events#broadcasting-events

Other than that, you could just have your Ajax response include the new data that needs to be appended to your DOM.

Post code if you need further help!